# Do antidepressants work?

Tags: medical-science, depression

I've been seeing occasional studies go by about the use of anti-depressants in treating depression.  Some seem to imply that they are at least over-prescribed (which may in itself not be all that bad, if the side effects are negligible), and that the primarily work by the placebo effect.  Anybody know something definite on this?

Comment: It would be helpful to elaborate on what you have read. It saves us from reiterating what you have read, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: The evidence base for different antidepressants is very different. Given that we closed the E-Number question I would also close this question and recommend to instead ask a question about a specific antidepressants.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes.** Antidepressants have been around for more than fifty years and are effective in treating depressive disorders. They do absolutely work.

> I've been seeing occasional studies..
>   ..that the[y] primarily work by the
>   placebo effect.

I think I know where you might be getting this idea.....

*Some members of the press and general public are questioning* the efficacy of **all** antidepressants based on the conclusions of a 2010 [meta-analysis](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/185157)* in which **two** antidepressants, [Imipramine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imipramine) and [Paroxetine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paroxetine), where used in the **six** studies *analyzed*. The analysis team concluded the following (emphasis mine):

> “[E]fforts
>   should be made to clarify to
>   clinicians and prospective patients
>   that whereas **[antidepressant
>   medication] can have a substantial
>   effect with more severe depressions**,
>   there is little evidence to suggest .
>   . . specific pharmacological benefit
>   for the majority of patients with less
>   severe acute depressions.”

Much of the confusion about the use of these drugs comes from using the term "depression" out of a medical context. There is a big difference between feeling *depressed* for a few days and having a *depressive disorder*. From the [NIMH](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/index.shtml):

> When a person has a depressive
>   disorder, it interferes with daily
>   life, normal functioning, and causes
>   pain for both the person with the
>   disorder and those who care about him
>   or her.

Some general forms of depressive disorder (also from the [NIMH](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/publications/depression/index.shtml))...

> - Major depressive disorder, also called major depression, is
>     characterized by a combination of
>     symptoms that interfere with a
>     person's ability to work, sleep,
>     study, eat, and enjoy once–pleasurable
>     activities. Major depression is
>     disabling and prevents a person from
>     functioning normally.
> - Dysthymic disorder, also called dysthymia, is characterized by
>     long–term (two years or longer) but
>     less severe symptoms that may not
>     disable a person but can prevent one
>     from functioning normally or feeling
>     well.
> - Psychotic depression, which occurs when a severe depressive illness is
>     accompanied by some form of psychosis,
>     such as a break with reality,
>     hallucinations, and delusions.

**[Meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis) can never follow the rules of science, for example being double-blind, controlled, or proposing a way to falsify the theory in question. It is only a statistical examination of scientific studies, not an actual scientific study, itself.*

---

> Anybody know something definite on
>   this?

[JAMA Psychiatry](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/) is a good starting point for researching the research.

Some random supporting research on antidepressants.....

- [Long-term antidepressant efficacy
  and safety of olanzapine/fluoxetine
  combination: A 76-week open-label
  study](https://www.psychiatrist.com/JCP/article/Pages/2003/v64n11/v64n1111.aspx) Conclusions: The
  olanzapine/fluoxetine combination
  showed rapid, robust, and sustained
  improvement in depressive symptoms in
  patients with MDD, including patients
  with TRD.
- [Treating Major Depression in Primary
  Care Practice](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/article-abstract/497659)   Results:
  Severity of depressive symptoms was
  reduced more rapidly and more
  effectively among patients randomized
  to pharmacotherapy or psychotherapy
  than among patients assigned to a
  physician's usual care.
- [Cognitive Therapy vs Medications in
  the Treatment of Moderate to Severe
  Depression](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/fullarticle/208460) Results: The
  advantage was significant for
  medication relative to placebo, and
  at the level of a nonsignificant
  trend for cognitive therapy relative
  to placebo.
- [Serotonin Function and the Mechanism
  of Antidepressant Action](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/article-abstract/495012)
- [Evidence of the Dual Mechanisms of
  Action of Venlafaxine](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/fullarticle/481597)

Antidepressant classifications:

1. [Serotonin–norepinephrine reuptake inhibitors (SNRIs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin%E2%80%93norepinephrine_reuptake_inhibitor)
2. [Selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_serotonin_reuptake_inhibitor)
3. [Monoamine oxidase inhibitors (MAOIs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_oxidase_inhibitor)
4. [Tricyclic antidepressants (TCAs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricyclic_antidepressant)

Comment: Second this. Apart from provably and observably working, one has to consider that most antidepressants have some quite serious and uncomfortable counter-effects. That's the major reason (besides having little or no effect on "normal" people) that there is zero abuse potential in them. No healthy person would take them. Yet, people with depressions _do_ take them. Why would they? Because the drugs help them, and they help much more than the adverse effects impact them.

Comment: There's a further classification that I know of, namely NMDA antagonists. Ketamine is the best known member of this class. Ketamine has some effects that make it fairly unsuitable as a therapy in the community but it does hold out hope that other NMDA antagonists will be added to the antidepressant armoury.

Comment: I have been reading a bit about all the buried and biased studies that was exposed a few years back. (http://www.rense.com/general81/1v.htm)

Do you have any comments on that?

Comment: Here to add that studies which show negative effects never get published. This is the same with medicine. Its actually a huge problem